# Rethrowing exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

Why doesn't the following doesn't handle the exception that was rethrown? I tried all the combinations but none of them would show the output in last catch so I'm confused!

```
Derived D;

try {
       throw D;
} catch ( const Derived &d) {
       throw;
} catch (const Base &b) {
      cout << "caught!" << endl;
}
```

---

```
Derived D;

try {
    throw D;
} catch ( const Derived d) {
    throw;
} catch (const Base b) {
    cout << "caught!" << endl;
}
```

---

```
Derived D;

try {
    throw D;
} catch ( const Derived d) {
    throw;
} catch (const Base &b) {
    cout << "caught!" << endl;
}
```

---

```
Derived D;

try {
    throw D;
} catch ( const Derived &d) {
    throw;
} catch (const Base b) {
    cout << "caught!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Well, you are not showing us the code that is expected to catch the rethrown exception. The next catch of the same try is *not* expected to catch it, only another try is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The re-throw is not handled by the same `try-catch` block. It's thrown up to the calling scope.

In `[except.throw]` (2003 wording):

> A throw-expression with no operand rethrows the exception being handled.

and:

> When an exception is thrown, control is transferred to the nearest handler with a matching type (15.3);
>   “nearest” means the handler for which the compound-statement, ctor-initializer, or function-body following
>   the try keyword was most recently entered by the thread of control **and not yet exited**.

Your `try` block has exited, so its handlers are not candidates. Thus, none of the `catch` blocks in your code may handle the re-throw.

Admittedly this is rather confusing wording.

Comment: Since the catch block is *outside* the block following `try`, the next catch is not eligible.

Comment: @Jan: I'm getting a headache, but don't the above conditions for `"nearest"` match? The next catch is a "handler", and the compound-statement following its relating `try` keyword has not yet exited. Oh, wait, yes it has. OK :D I stand by everything in my answer, but thanks for helping me understand it myself ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. As I understand, the exception is only handled if the catch has its own try block.

Comment: @user753213: I don't follow. "Matches" how?

Comment: Edited, I meant to say, for a catch that is related with a try block.

Comment: @user753213: Still not really getting you. The rules are as stated in my answer, anyway: Given `try { A } catch (B) { C } catch (D) { E }`, the only things caught by those catch blocks are exceptions thrown in `A`. Exceptions thrown in `C` and `E` are separate and distinct, and this includes rethrows.

Comment: Yes, that is how i understand. When an exception is rethrown from a catch handler, It has to be handled by a catch handler that has its own seperate try block.

Comment: @user753213: That's not how I'd word it, but I think you get it.

Comment: I was thinking 'How rethrow is handled' but yours cover the way how an exception is handled including rethrows, I think which makes more sense :)

Answer (score 9):

Rethrown exception is supposed to be caught by some other `try..catch` block, not the catch handler of the same `try` block. See this example:

```
using namespace std;
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base(){}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

void f()
{
    try
    {
        throw Derived();
    }
    catch(Derived& ex)
    {
        cout<<"Caught in f\n";
        throw;
    }

}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        f();
    }
    catch(Base& b)
    {
        cout<<"Caught in main\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output is:

> Caught in f
>
> Caught in main

Comment: Another way to put it: the `catch` only catches exceptions that try to leave the context of the block immediately following the `try` keyword.

Comment: The example seems a little redundant. The question is the example. :)

Answer (score 3):

This should work :

```
Derived D;


try{

    try {
        throw D;
    } catch ( const Derived &d) {
        throw;
    } catch (const Base &b) {
        cout << "caught!" << endl;
    }

} catch (const Base &b) {
    cout << "caught here!" << endl;
}
```

As other said, the `rethrow` will rethrow the same exception out of the catch block.