# Can exceptions be thrown if I don't use throw keyword inside try block?

Tags: c++, exception

Consider the following code snippet:

```
try
{
    //Code without a single throw keyword
}
catch(...)
{
    cout<<"Exception thrown";
}
```

EDIT: The functions called inside the `try` block also don't contain `throw` keyword anywhere.

Can the catch block ever get executed?

Comment: Yes. An operation (e.g. a function call) within the `try` block can throw.

Comment: The functions called inside try also don't use throw keyword. I have edited my question to indicate this

Comment: Same thing then goes for all the operations (not just functions, mind), and every operation within every operation, and so on.

Comment: Which compiler and what options are used? Some compilers can throw asynchronous exceptions (e.g. `/EHa` with MSVC). If there are any standard library containers or function calls there, then they could throw (even if it is from a single call to `new`).

Comment: @biffen Yes, that's pretty much what i mean

Comment: @niall Sir, I am talking about runtime exceptions

Comment: @JobinJose. So am I. MSVC can throw an exception (catchable with `...`) if there is an access violation (e.g. dereferencing a `nullptr`) if the code is compile with that support.

Comment: @JobinJose, exceptions also can be throwned by library functions, for example http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: You got it backwards. You should consider every piece of C++ code such that it could throw exceptions until proven otherwise. In modern C++, "proven otherwise" here translates to `noexcept`. Required reading: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec

Comment: The only way to be sure that nothing throws is to use `-fno-exceptions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  One of the things you do in the try block may throw its own exception on failure.

Some things do not have a throw keyword on them but they could still throw.  `new` by default throws on failure so if any of your code uses `new` you could still have an exception raised.  It really depends on the code that you are using.

Comment: You mean its possible that the operating system could throw an exception when it comes across a problem in the code at runtime?

Comment: @JobinJose I added some more to my answer.

Comment: @JobinJose It is not the operating system, which throws the exception. It is the standard C/C++ library, which is linked to your binary.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely yes. In C++ if `new` fails to allocate memory, it by default will throw a `std::badalloc` exception. Since lots of C++ code calls `new`, throwing an exception is always a possibility.

Answer (score 4):

You got it backwards. You should consider *every* piece of C++ code such that it could throw exceptions until proven otherwise. In modern C++, "proven otherwise" here translates to [`noexcept`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec).

Comment: `noexcept` actually makes the generate code as if nothing underneath will throw.  It doesn't actually raise an compile time error if anything underneath actually do throw.  It's quite pointless.

Answer (score 3):

Standard C++ gives you very few ways of throwing an exception. The most important is the `throw` keyword. There's also `exception_ptr::rethrow_exception`. There's also some other standard features such as a failing `operator new`, a failing `dynamic_cast`, and `typeid` on a null pointer, which are specified to throw in case of failure, but are effectively part of the language runtime which means they do not directly constitute a `throw`, even if the actual implementation probably uses `throw` internally.

However, not all code you interface with is necessarily standard C++. For a long time, the Microsoft compiler supported a feature where a `catch(...)` could catch system errors such as access violations. Under GCC, an exception of a different language (e.g. a Java exception in code compiled with GCJ) could be also caught with a catch.

And of course, `throw` itself is implemented by the compiler in some way, and low-level code could emulate this without actually using `throw`, possibly by calling special functions of the language runtime or by using `asm` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

`try` may contain call to some functions, operator, write operations with bad cast, bad maths, resource error etc which can throw uncaught `throw` or may [rethrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185957/rethrowing-exceptions). Such a catch block may get executed in such cases.